# This Akka stream sometimes doesn't finish

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a graph that reads lines from multiple gzipped files and writes those lines to another set of gzipped files, mapped according to some value in each line.

It works correctly against small data sets, but fails to terminate on larger data. (It may not be the size of the data that's to blame, as I have not run it enough times to be sure - it takes a while).

```
def files: Source[File, NotUsed] =
  Source.fromIterator(
    () =>
      Files
        .fileTraverser()
        .breadthFirst(inDir)
        .asScala
        .filter(_.getName.endsWith(".gz"))
        .toIterator)

def extract =
  Flow[File]
    .mapConcat[String](unzip)
    .mapConcat(s =>
      (JsonMethods.parse(s) \ "tk").extract[Array[String]].map(_ -> s).to[collection.immutable.Iterable])
    .groupBy(1 << 16, _._1)
    .groupedWithin(1000, 1.second)
    .map { lines =>
      val w = writer(lines.head._1)
      w.println(lines.map(_._2).mkString("\n"))
      w.close()
      Done
    }
    .mergeSubstreams

def unzip(f: File) = {
  scala.io.Source
    .fromInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(f)))
    .getLines
    .toIterable
    .to[collection.immutable.Iterable]
}

def writer(tk: String): PrintWriter =
  new PrintWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(
      new GZIPOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream(new File(outDir, s"$tk.json.gz"), true)
      ))
  )

val process = files.via(extract).toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.right).run()

Await.result(process, Duration.Inf)
```

The thread dump shows that the process is `WAITING` at `Await.result(process, Duration.Inf)` and nothing else is happening.

OpenJDK v11 with Akka v2.5.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's stuck in `groupBy` because it ran out of available threads in dispatcher to gather items into 2^16 groups for all sources.

So if I were you I'd probably implement grouping in `extract` semi-manually using `statefulMapConcat` with mutable `Map[KeyType, List[String]]`. Or buffer lines with `groupedWithin` first and split them into groups that you would write to different files in `Sink.foreach`.

Comment: Indeed, I have tried this pattern a couple of times now. Not only does it often hang, but it's also quite slow. I came to the same conclusion as you and reimplemented with the buffering approach.